# Is there an USB adapter for secondary display with RCA output?

Tags: usb, video, vga, display-adapter, rca

I need to use my TV as a second monitor for my notebook. But I'd like to use the TV's AV input (RCA).

My notebook's VGA output is broken, so I'll need to buy an external video adapter. I've seen many USB to VGA adapters, and I've seen also some VGA to RCA converters. so, that would do the trick.

But I was wondering, **does anyone know about a USB adapter for secondary display with a RCA output?**

Comment: SInce you want to use RCA, I am assuming you dont have a HDTV.  If that is the case, you dont want to use that TV as a monitor.  The resolution will be to low and it will look very bad.

Comment: Actually, it is a HDTV. But there's already a RCA cable installed through the wall, so I would like to make use of it.

Comment: is the connector on your TV component or composite?  Either way, both of those are analog.  Component video does support low end HD, it still wont look that great.  You really want a digital connection.

Comment: The simplest way to determine if a USB to VGA adapter exists is to look for one.  If you can't find out, it safe to say, it does not exist.  Honestly its not 100% clear what type of adapter you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of USB->VGA adapters on the market.  You can also Google "USB component video" for the kind of setup you're looking for as well.

A word of warning, though...

The MAXIMUM resolution a set of component video cables can carry is 854x480 progressive scan -- far, far below the resolution of any modern computer screen.  A computer probably wouldn't even be usable at that resolution for anything other than a presentation screen.

Note that this assumes COMPONENT video (i.e. the kind with red, green, and blue video connector ends -- even though they do not correspond to RGB video).  If you have a COMPOSITE connection (i.e. a single yellow connector), then the resolution is even lower -- 624x480 interlaced.  If you want progressive scan over composite, you'd have to go 320x240.  Note that this is the resolution of the original Nintendo circa 1983.  No modern computer will operate at that resolution.